# Symfony Form OneToMany Entity ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: symfony

Three entities exists; Topic, Meta and User.

Topic OneToMany Meta ManyToOne User

How can this be created using Symfony Forms?

Originally this was a ManyToMany relationship between Topic and User but this has been altered to allow additional information about the relationship to be stored in Meta.

Original form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('users')
    ;
}
```

Modified form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('users', EntityType::class, [
            'multiple' => true,
            'class' => 'FooBarBundle:User',                
            'choice_label' => 'username',
            ])
    ;
}
```

This renders a form with Title and a multi select for User.  The problem is User doesn't map to Meta and so the User data won't be persisted.  Is `mapped=false` and using the controller to attach the Meta entity to Thread the correct way to handle this relationship?  Or is there a way to use a `DataTransformer` to convert the Users to Metas?

--- UPDATE ---

```
public function setUsers($users) {
    foreach($users AS $user) {
        $meta = new Meta();
        $meta
            ->setUser($user)
            ->setThread($this);
        $this->addMeta($meta);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Or is using the call from within `Form::handleRequest` to `Thread::setUsers` the right place to convert a User to a Meta?

Comment: You can leave form like it is and deal with creating Meta objects (and filling them with user and topic objects) in controller (after validation form). I'm doing that this way. IMO fastest way and give you most control.

Comment: Did you look at moving that logic to the Thread entity instead? i.e. when the form handles the request it calls `Thread::setUsers()` in this method you could convert each User to a Meta entity? I will update the question with a example. Is moving the logic to the entity bad practice?

Comment: Full example is here [Many-to-many association example in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/toza/many-to-many-association-example-in-symfony) Student (1 to n) -> StudentSubject <- (n to 1) Subject